# Sqlite3 ON DELETE CASCADE does not work

Tags: sqlite

I have got multiple tables in my database. I am going to use only 2 of them as an example.

Basket table:

```
CREATE TABLE Basket(
id_basket integer primary key autoincrement,
title text)
```

Computer table:

```
CREATE TABLE Computer(
id_computer integer primary key autoincrement,
basket integer,
title text,
foreign key (basket) references Basket(id_basket) on delete cascade)
```

Then I execute the `pragma foreign_keys = on` query.

According to what I found here earlier, should I delete a row from Basket table to which some of the Computer table rows refer, these rows from Computer table shall be deleted too. But for some reason I get this error: Query Error: `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed Unable to fetch row`.

I will be grateful for any suggestions, thank you in advance.

Here are some images with table data:

[select * from basket query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AaIw.png)

[select * from computer query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqVWJ.png)

Sqlite version: 3.8.2

Comment: Do you have permissions to delete at all?

Comment: Yes. If I turn foreign_keys off and attempt to delete the same row from Basket, it works. But all the rows from Computer that refer to that row remain in the database. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Can you include sample data for which the delete is failing?  I don't see why you should be getting this error.

Comment: I hope I understood correctly what you asked and uploaded 2 images with Basket and Computer tables data. What I do before getting that error described in my question is attempt to execute this query: `delete from basket where id_basket = 1`. Hoping that 1 row form Basket will be deleted and all the rows from Computer that refer to it. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/792b5/2). There is something wrong with your data.

Comment: What database client is this? Are you sure it's not creating a new connection for subsequent queries? If so, you need to execute the `pragma` statement as part of each query. Can you try using a different client than Sqliteman?

Comment: No, it doesn't work anywhere. And executing `pragma foreign_keys = on` with each query also doesn't help. Even in the sqlfiddle.com link that @CL provided it doesn't work. @AlvinThompson

Comment: The SQLFiddle link shows that it works. What, exactly, do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @CL: It does not return the `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed Unable to fetch row` error in SQLFiddle, but for some reason it also does not delete row from Basket with `DELETE FROM Basket WHERE id_basket = 1` if there are rows in Computer that refer to this particular row.

Comment: It does; the second SELECT does not return anything.

Comment: @CL: Really weird. It doesn't delete anything for me and selects return 1 row from basket and 2 rows from computer. Just what was inserted...

Comment: @CL I had a mistake in some other table (not included here as an example) schema which did not allow cascade delete for that table. Though it actually worked for Basket and Computer, some time later this cascade delete action reached that table and now that's where the FK constraint error occurred. I feel really dumb now not being able to find the mistake for like a week. But consider this solved now.