# before delete trigger low performance

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, relational-database

I am writing a C++ application in QT Creator also using an SQLite database connection. What I want to achieve is that when I delete a row from a table, rows from other tables that refer to it are deleted too. So in my case if I delete a row from Basket, referring rows from Computer are also deleted, then from subsystemtable, subscriber, regulations and so on until the end.

Here is my database diagram:

[image: DB Diagram]

I have created triggers for each table that have foreign key references with another tables.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk BEFORE DELETE ON Basket
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM Computer WHERE computer.basket = old.id_basket;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_comp BEFORE DELETE ON computer
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM subsystemtable WHERE subsystemtable.computer = id.id_computer;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_subscriber_map BEFORE DELETE ON subscriber
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM mappingtable WHERE mappingtable.subscriber = old.id_subscriber;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_subscriber_indirect BEFORE DELETE ON subscriber
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM indirectsubscriber WHERE indirectsubscriber.subscriber = old.id_subscriber;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_subscriber BEFORE DELETE ON subscriber
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM reserve WHERE reserve.subscriber = old.id_subscriber;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_subscriber_res BEFORE DELETE ON subscriber
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM reserve WHERE reserve.subscriber_res = old.id_subscriber;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_subs BEFORE DELETE ON subsystem
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM subsystemtable WHERE subsystemtable.subsystem = old.id_subsystem;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_substable_reg BEFORE DELETE ON subsystemtable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM regulations WHERE regulations.subsystem = old.id;
END

CREATE TRIGGER delete_fk_substable BEFORE DELETE ON subsystemtable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM subscriber WHERE subscriber.subsystem = old.id;
END
```

I got what I wanted. And it works exactly like I wanted. But my problem now is the low performance. So in my database I have about 20 computers for each basket, then about 5 subsystems for each computer, 100 subscribers for each subsystem and so on. When i delete 1 single basket the whole procedure takes about 400 ms. Should I delete 3 baskets at once, it will take more than 3 seconds already.

I need to find a way for this to work way faster. Limited by about 200-300 ms, I guess. And I need any suggestions about how can I do it.

Comment: Take some other, more mature database system? PostgreSQL, for example. Or use foreign keys properly, explained here: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions. `CASCADE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implementing foreign keys by hand.
This is not necessary; you can just use [ON DELETE actions](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) to let the DB do the appropriate changes.

Whether you are implementing foreign keys manually or with the help of the DB, you need to create [indexes on certain key columns](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes), or all the lookups needed to find related rows will be slow.

Comment: Specifically, when creating the foreign key constraint you should use the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option. For example, since `Computer` refers to `Basket`, you should add a foreign key constant to `id_basket`. Then if a row in `Basket` is deleted, any row in `Computer` where `id_basket` refers to it is also automatically deleted. No need to mess with triggers at all.

Comment: For some reason ON DELETE CASCADE does not work for me. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588039/sqlite3-on-delete-cascade-does-not-work. And I can only use SQlite. @Alvin

Comment: @EgorChubarov: Not sure what the issue is. Are you sure you're executing `pragma foreign_keys = on` every time you establish a new connection to the DB, and that everything that connects to the DB executes this pragma?